# CheckChanged event called when trying to switch to another TAB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs

I have some radiobuttons on some tabs, when I click on one it generates an Excel-file.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbAantallen1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                GroupName="Soort" oncheckedchanged="rbRapport_CheckedChanged" 
                Text="Aantallen" />
```

The bug happens when I want to switch to the other tab. It keeps generating Excel-files. What can I do to stop running the checkedchanged event and SWITCH IN PEACE TO ANOTHER TAB?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MyDataSource.SelectCommand = @"
                    select  melder_account, 
                            aanvraag_titel, 
                            fase_datum_opgelost_oplosser, 
                            Melding_niveau_2,
                            rapporteren, 
                            fase_datum_gestart, 
                            fase_datum_opgelost, 
                            doorlooptijd, 
                            jurentkode
                    from uvw_HD_AANVRAAG_DOORLOOPTIJD_ALGEMEEN
                    where Melding_niveau_1 = 'Brandje'";
            }
        }

    protected void MenuTabs_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value);
        multiTabs.ActiveViewIndex = index;
        MyDataSource.SelectCommand = BepaalDataSource(index);
    }

    public string BepaalDataSource(int index)
    {
        string select = @"
            select  melder_account, 
                    aanvraag_titel, 
                    fase_datum_opgelost_oplosser, 
                    Melding_niveau_2,
                    rapporteren, 
                    fase_datum_gestart, 
                    fase_datum_opgelost, 
                    doorlooptijd, 
                    jurentkode
            from uvw_HD_AANVRAAG_DOORLOOPTIJD_ALGEMEEN
            where Melding_niveau_1 = '";
        if (index == 0)
        {
            cbPage.Checked = false;
            return select += "Brandje'";
        }
        else
        {
            cbPage.Checked = true;
            return select += "System - Netwerk'";
        }
    }

    public DataView GetDataFromDataSource()
    {
        MyDataSource.SelectCommand = BepaalDataSource(Convert.ToInt16(cbPage.Checked));
        return MyDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
    }

    protected void rbRapport_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtOriginal = (DataTable)GetDataFromDataSource().ToTable(); //Return Table consisting data
        DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable(); //Create Temporary Table

        //Creating Header Row
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Melder</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Onderwerp</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Oplosser</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Niveau 2</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Rapporteren</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Gestart op</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Opgelost op</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Doorlooptijd</b>");
        dtTemp.Columns.Add("<b>Jurentkode</b>");
        DataRow drAddItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtOriginal.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            drAddItem = dtTemp.NewRow();
            drAddItem[0] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][0].ToString();//Melder
            drAddItem[1] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][1].ToString();//Onderwerp
            drAddItem[2] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][2].ToString();//Oplosser
            drAddItem[3] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][3].ToString();//Niveau 2
            drAddItem[4] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][4].ToString();//Rapporteren
            drAddItem[5] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][5].ToString();//Gestart op
            drAddItem[6] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][6].ToString();//Opgelost op
            drAddItem[7] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][7].ToString();//Doorlooptijd
            drAddItem[8] = dtOriginal.Rows[i][8].ToString();//Jurentkode
            dtTemp.Rows.Add(drAddItem);
        }

        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid(); //Temp Grid
        dg.DataSource = dtTemp;
        dg.DataBind();

        ExportToExcel("Rapport.xls", dg);
        dg = null;
        dg.Dispose();
    }

    private void ExportToExcel(string strFileName, DataGrid dg)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        dg.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

    protected void cbRapport_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: can you post your "ASPX" page definition for the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things come to mind.

In your rbRapport_CheckChanged() function you could check to make sure the radio button is visible.

You could also check your tab control to make sure you're on the right tab.

**EDIT**
Based on your comments, the hosting tab is invisible.

If that's the case, do something like this in your code

```
rbRapport_CheckChanged()
{
    if(tab1.Visible == false)
        return;

    <rest of code here>
}
```

Where tab1 is the tab that rbRapport is on.  This will check, if the tab isn't visible, you probably don't want to create an xls, so it will just short circuit and kick out of the event.   If the tab is visible, it will process the event.

**Edit**
maybe you shouldn't be creating the xls when your radio button changes. Maybe you should have a button to click that says "Generate XLS" or something, and capture that click event. – taylonr Apr 28 at 11:42

Comment: If the rbRapport_CheckChanged() is getting called when you're switching tabs then it might.  I've seen behavior like this where a similar event would get called when switching tabs...

Comment: When the CheckChanged() event is firing, are you sure that the correct tab is visible?  I've seen it happen where tab1 has the button and tab2 is visible when the event gets fired.  That would cause your xls to get created when switching tabs.

Comment: Ok, then put a breakpoint in the CheckChanged event.  Gather as much information as you can about when that event fires, then write code so you only process the event when you mean to (i.e. you're on the right tab, it's visible etc)

Comment: the tab is not visible, but it keeps calling the checkchanged event. really don't know why :s

Comment: It calls it because events aren't stopped just when something is invisible.

Comment: I don't think it's logic to check the visibility of the tabs. there must be something to stop the event. because the radiobutton is still checked even if I wish to go to the other tab.

Comment: You can ubsubscribe from the event, but then you'd need to resubscribe when you come back into the tab.

Comment: It's a lot more work, because on tab change events you'd have to make sure you're subscribed, then unsubscribe (if you try while you're not subscribed it throws an exception)  Then you'd have to check if you're changing to the tab you want an resubscribe.  That's why I said just add a check when you're firing the CheckChanged event

Comment: It's difficult to check for visibility of tabs. Because I will need a BIG check, and I have other radiobuttons who use the same eventhandler.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't be creating the xls when your radio button changes.  Maybe you should have a button to click that says "Generate XLS" or something, and capture that click event.

Comment: okay I think it's better than losing time in looking for a complex solution.

Comment: Hey taylonr, post your comment so that I will accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code provided. Please ensure that, you have not bind this `rbRapport_CheckedChanged` function with any other control's event like TabChangedEvent or CheckedChange event of other radio button which values will be changing based on tab change etc.

If not so, there may be problem with the parent controls of the RadioButton.